# how to add different colors to the Image resource randomly

Tags: android, android-resources

I am having a circular image view

```
circleImageView.setImageResource(R.color.colorPrimary);
```

Instead of colorPrimary i want to add random colors

I have a array

```
arraystring = {R.color.colorPrimary,R.color.blue,R.color.red}
```

i used random function method to assign

```
String randomStr = arraystring [new Random().nextInt(array.length)];
```

but i cant give

```
circleImageView.setImageResource(randomStr);
```

Is their any other methods to give,can any one suggest it please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first declare the array as integer array

```
int[] colors = new int[] {R.color.colorPrimary,R.color.blue,R.color.red};
```

the choose from the integer array randomly

```
int randomColor = colors[new Random().nextInt(colors.length)];
```

finally set the color of the ImageView as follows

```
circleImageView.setImageDrawable(new ColorDrawable(randomColor));
```

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 1):

you need to add array of colors in color.xml and reference them to int[] in java code like this

```
int[] colors=context.getResources().getIntArray(R.array.borders);
    int randomColor=colors[new Random().nextInt(colors.length)];
         circularImageView.setBackgroundColor(randomColor);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should pass Int instead so create a method return `@DrawableRes` `Int` and then use Random to pick up a random int from that array